# Problema en tipos boolean y numeric no son coincidentes en CASE, Postgresql

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-12

Tengo este codigo:

```
update liquidacion set subt = 

(case
when suelcar < ((select val_salmin from valores)*2) then ((select val_subt from valores)*diast)

else suelcar = 0

end)

from

cargos join empleados on empleados.codcar=cargos.codcar join diastrabajados on 
empleados.cedemp=diastrabajados.cedemp

where

nomemp = empleado;
```

### El problema es que al ejecutarlo me aparece este error:

ERROR:  los tipos boolean y numeric no son coincidentes en CASE

LINE 3: ...lcar < ((select val_salmin from valores)*2) then ((select va...

```
                                                   ^
```

SQL state: 42804

Character: 96

no se porque pasa:(

Comment: De que va tu consulta, que quieres hacer?

Comment: Me parece que el mensaje de error es bastante claro, estás comparando un valor booleano con un valor numérico. ¿Qué es exactamente `suelcar` en tu consulta y de qué tipo es?

Comment: si osea suelcar es numerico, val_salmin es numerico, val_subt es numerico, diast es numerico